# 'requestTracker must be an instance of RequestTracker' when implementing a cassandra-driver RequestTracker in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, cassandra

I'm currently implementing a class that implements `RequestTracker` interface from `cassandra-driver` module in TypeScript. I've got an error 'requestTracker must be an instance of RequestTracker' when running the code. The code compile just fine.

Here's a test code to reproduce the issue.

```js
import {Client, Host, ExecutionOptions, tracker, types} from 'cassandra-driver'

class ATracker implements tracker.RequestTracker{
    onError(
        host: Host,
        query: string | Array<{ query: string, params?: any }>,
        parameters: any[] | { [key: string]: any } | null,
        executionOptions: ExecutionOptions,
        requestLength: number,
        err: Error,
        latency: number[]): void{

        }
  
      onSuccess(
        host: Host,
        query: string | Array<{ query: string, params?: any }>,
        parameters: any[] | { [key: string]: any } | null,
        executionOptions: ExecutionOptions,
        requestLength: number,
        responseLength: number,
        latency: number[]): void{

        }
  
      shutdown(): void{

      }
}

let client = new Client({
    requestTracker: new ATracker,
    contactPoints: ['localhost'],
    keyspace: 'keyspace',
    localDataCenter: 'datacenter1',
    queryOptions: { consistency: types.consistencies.localQuorum }
});

client.connect();
```

When I run the above code, I've got an exception :

```
D:\tstest\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\client-options.js:144
    throw new TypeError('requestTracker must be an instance of RequestTracker');
    ^

TypeError: requestTracker must be an instance of RequestTracker
    at Object.extend (D:\tstest\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\client-options.js:144:11)
    at new Client (D:\tstest\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\client.js:402:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\tstest\src\main.js:15:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

which is thrown by this piece of code

```js
  if (options.requestTracker !== null && !(options.requestTracker instanceof tracker.RequestTracker)) {
    throw new TypeError('requestTracker must be an instance of RequestTracker');
  }
```

So the question is, is there any way to implement the interface in TypeScript? I have tried implementing it in JavaScript and it works just fine, but it will be foreign in the TS code-base.

The reason why I'm implementing this interface is I have to track CQL statements that does not work with AWS KeySpaces (Amazon's implementation of CQL database).